# WPF Binding and Observable Model fail

Tags: c#, wpf

In a simple trying-to-learn-WPF experiment I'm trying to bind a property ("InternalName") of an instance of MyModel to the contents of TextBlock "MainWindowTextBlock". Clicking the ``ChangeNameButton" changes the InternalName property of mymodel, but that property change never makes it through to the TextBlock. Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

XMAL

```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlExperiments"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row ="0">
            <Button Width="100" Height="20" Name="ChangeName" Content="Change the Name" Click="ChangeNameButtonClick"/>
            <TextBlock Text=""/>
            <TextBlock  Name="MainWindowTextBox" Width="100" Height="20" Text="{Binding Path = mymodel.InternalName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MyModel mymodel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this.DataContext;
            mymodel = new MyModel("The old name");          
                               
        }
        private void ChangeNameButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mymodel.InternalName = "A new name!";
        }
    }
    public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string internalname;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public MyModel(string nm)
        {
            InternalName = nm;   
        }    
       protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public string InternalName
        {
            get { return internalname; }
            set
            {
                if (internalname != value)
                {
                    internalname = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("InternalName");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you posted, your first-order bug is here: `DataContext = this.DataContext;`. That statements does nothing. It's just copying the value of the `DataContext` property to itself. You probably meant something like `DataContext = this;`. That said, you are better off making the view model object _itself_ the `DataContext`, rather than making the `Window` object its own `DataContext. Obviously, if you make that change, you'll have to update the binding path accordingly.

Comment: For future reference, you should always look at the debugger's "Debug" output window. Binding errors are displayed there (among other things), and I would expect the above code to produce an error (the `DataContext` would remain `null`, so the path `mymodel.InternalName` would not be able to be resolved)

Comment: @PeterDuniho, thx. Yes, the DataContext setting made no sense, I was indeed trying DataContext=this; (which doesn't work either). However using DataContext=mymodel does work, provided I revise the Binding Path to, just, "InternalName"

Comment: Xaml binding failures may now appear in a new window specifically intended for these. Or they may not. There are vs settings control this behaviour. I would also differentiate between a model and viewmodel. In trivial apps then it doesn't matter but in business apps have a model class as a dto and separate viewmodel with view adaptive code in it. Use automapper ( or something else ) to copy between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following markup tries to bind to a *property*  named "mymodel" of the current `DataContext` of the `TextBlock`, which is inherited from the parent window:

```
<TextBlock Name="MainWindowTextBox"
           Text="{Binding Path = mymodel.InternalName}"/>
```

So you need to set the `DataContext` of the window to itself:

```
DataContext = this;
```

And you also need to make `mymodel` a *public property* since you cannot bind to fields:

```
public MyModel mymodel { get; }
```

Then it should work but you probably also want to change the name of the property to comply with the C# naming standards.

You can also remove `Mode=TwoWay` from the binding. It makes no sense for a `TextBlock`.